# Best Practices for saving images in swift (ios)

Tags: ios, swift, database, image

So I need to save pictures (made by the user) inside the app. I don't want to send them to a server and keep the link.

I am currently using Realm to save data, but I heard that it was not ideal to save images. What are the best practices for saving images locally?

(I will sometimes need to save hundreds of images.)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager - try FileManager if you want to save on apps sandbox

Comment: After more research, I found this post on stack exchange about keeping it in the file system and reducing the size (I was mainly scared of using too much space on the user's phone). https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164905/how-best-to-store-images-on-a-file-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of your data do you save ? ( link, data, image).
You should convert image to base64 then you save them into Realm. let write them in background task.
it will reduce volume and time to store them in Realm.